# How can I work around setting IsChecked for ToggleButton in GotFocus event causing both Checked and Unchecked events to be called?

Tags: c#, wpf, togglebutton

**Requirements**

When a user tabs to one of the toggle buttons, I want it to be checked and uncheck any other toggle buttons.  If a user clicks on a toggle button, it's state should change from either checked to unchecked or unchecked to checked.

**Issue**

Setting the `IsChecked` property in the `GotFocus` event for a `ToggleButton` causes the `Checked` event to be called and then mysteriously unchecks the `ToggleButton` and causes the `Unchecked` event to be called.

**Code**

Here is the sample code from my lab project that demonstrates this.

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel x:Name="ToggleButtonContainer" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ToggleButton Content="Toggle 1" Margin="2" Padding="4" GotFocus="ToggleButton_GotFocus" Checked="ToggleButton_Checked" Unchecked="ToggleButton_Unchecked" />
        <ToggleButton Content="Toggle 2" Margin="2" Padding="4" GotFocus="ToggleButton_GotFocus" Checked="ToggleButton_Checked" Unchecked="ToggleButton_Unchecked" />
        <ToggleButton Content="Toggle 3" Margin="2" Padding="4" GotFocus="ToggleButton_GotFocus" Checked="ToggleButton_Checked" Unchecked="ToggleButton_Unchecked" />
        <ToggleButton Content="Toggle 4" Margin="2" Padding="4" GotFocus="ToggleButton_GotFocus" Checked="ToggleButton_Checked" Unchecked="ToggleButton_Unchecked" />
        <ToggleButton Content="Toggle 5" Margin="2" Padding="4" GotFocus="ToggleButton_GotFocus" Checked="ToggleButton_Checked" Unchecked="ToggleButton_Unchecked" />
    </StackPanel>    
</Grid>
```

CODE:

```
    private void ToggleButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("INFO:  ToggleButton_Checked called by {0}", sender);
        foreach (var toggleButton in ToggleButtonContainer.Children)
        {
            if (toggleButton != sender &&
                (toggleButton as ToggleButton).IsChecked.HasValue &&
                (toggleButton as ToggleButton).IsChecked.Value)
            {
                (toggleButton as ToggleButton).IsChecked = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void ToggleButton_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("INFO:  ToggleButton_Unchecked called by {0}", sender);
    }

    private void ToggleButton_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("INFO:  ToggleButton_GotFocus called by {0}", sender);
        (sender as ToggleButton).IsChecked = true;
    }
```

**Environment Info**

- Visual Studio 2013 Update 4
- Windows 8 / Windows 10
- .NET Framework 4.5

**Observations**

I have observed that if I click the button and drag away from it before releasing the left mouse button, then I don't experience the issue.  This also happens when you debug and step through the `Checked` event (because again, the `ToggleButton` never receives the `MouseLeftButtonUp` event since the debugger has taken focus).

**Questions**

- Why does the button become unchecked?
- Is this a bug in WPF or am I just doing something incorrectly?
- What is a good work around to resolve this issue?  (if there is a good, clean work around)

Comment: Can you use the ToggleButton's `Click` method instead of `Checked`? Checked is going to fire any time the button is checked, regardless if it's programmatically being checked, or being checked by the user.

Comment: I get the same behavior either way.  It doesn't matter whether I use the Click event or the Checked/Unchecked combo events.  This seems to be because, by the time the user releases the mouse (which is when the Click event occurs), the ToggleButton has already been mysteriously moved back to IsChecked = false.

Comment: Why don't you use RadioButton? It does the unchecking automatically...

Comment: @Greg, that doesn't fill the requirements.  Users cannot toggle a RadioButton from Checked to Unchecked by clicking on it, plus I need the style of a ToggleButton.

Comment: Problem is that you get the focus first, which sets the IsChecked = true, then when it gets to click event, it will do IsChecked = !IsChecked. So this causes the untoggling. You could consider writing your own togglebutton implementation that does what you require.

Comment: What do you think does the default behaviour for togglebutton? Magic possibly? You are not overriding the default click handler. Make your own togglebutton, inherit togglebutton and override the onclick and add these Debug.WriteLine(this.IsChecked); base.OnClick(); Debug.WriteLine(this.IsChecked); the printed values will be True and then False, if you set the IsChecked = true; when the togglebutton gets focus.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry.  I understand WHY it changes the value.  What I don't understand is why the control doesn't account for a programmatic change in value.  When it's firing off these events, it should be able to recognize the change since the IsChecked property is a DependencyProperty and realize that the value has already been changed and does not need to be changed further.

Comment: @Janne, this discussion with you on creating my own ToggleButton control has lead me to a usable solution, thanks!  Do you want to post an answer that has a complete example of this?

Comment: I'm unsure what the solution is, so maybe not, just post yourself :) Also the Checked and UnChecked are just events that happen when IsChecked is set to true or false.

Comment: Well, I'm very CLOSE to a solution.  I added a focusActivated boolean that is set by the OnGotFocus and checked by the OnClick method.  However, there is still a problem because when the user tabs to a button (which successfully sets IsChecked to true), if the user tries to toggle it off, the toggle off won't work because the focusActivated flag is still set and I haven't figured out a good way to clear it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the button become unchecked?

The button becomes unchecked because the `IsChecked` property is changed in the `GotFocus` event, but then it is changed back when the `OnClick` method fires.

> Is this a bug in WPF or am I just doing something incorrectly?

It appears that the current ToggleButton was designed with the intention that the only control for selecting/unselecting it lies with the mouse left button click or the spacebar.

> What is a good work around to resolve this issue? (if there is a good, clean work around)

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11787674/291638) and the conversation with Janne Matikainen, I was able to come up with the following solution:

```
public class MyToggleButton : ToggleButton
{
    protected override void OnGotKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.Tab))
        {
            IsChecked = true;
            base.OnGotKeyboardFocus(e);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnLostFocus(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsChecked = false;
        base.OnLostFocus(e);
    }
}
```

Replacing all of the instances of <ToggleButton> with <uc:MyToggleButton> produces the behavior as specified in the Requirements section of the question text.

Comment: How does it will work if you try to check/uncheck the focused control?

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if this works for you.

XAML

```
<Grid>
        <StackPanel x:Name="ToggleButtonContainer" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" Content="Toggle 1" Margin="2" Padding="4" GotFocus="ToggleButton_GotFocus" Checked="ToggleButton_Checked" Unchecked="ToggleButton_Unchecked" />
            <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" Content="Toggle 2" Margin="2" Padding="4" GotFocus="ToggleButton_GotFocus" Checked="ToggleButton_Checked" Unchecked="ToggleButton_Unchecked" />
            <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" Content="Toggle 3" Margin="2" Padding="4" GotFocus="ToggleButton_GotFocus" Checked="ToggleButton_Checked" Unchecked="ToggleButton_Unchecked" />
            <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" Content="Toggle 4" Margin="2" Padding="4" GotFocus="ToggleButton_GotFocus" Checked="ToggleButton_Checked" Unchecked="ToggleButton_Unchecked" />
            <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" Content="Toggle 5" Margin="2" Padding="4" GotFocus="ToggleButton_GotFocus" Checked="ToggleButton_Checked" Unchecked="ToggleButton_Unchecked" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

CODE:

```
 private void ToggleButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("INFO:  ToggleButton_Checked called by {0}", sender);
        }

        private void ToggleButton_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("INFO:  ToggleButton_Unchecked called by {0}", sender);
        }

        private void ToggleButton_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("INFO:  ToggleButton_GotFocus called by {0}", sender);
            (sender as ToggleButton).IsChecked = true;
        }
```

Comment: -1 This does not fulfill the requirements since the user cannot toggle from checked state to unchecked state.  Not only that, but I need the visual appearance of a Button, thus ToggleButton.

Comment: I'm using the style of ToggleButton to show the appearance of a button <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"

Comment: Still doesn't change the fact that the user cannot click an already checked button in order to uncheck it.

Comment: Not sure if you tried this code, but if you use it, the previously selected button gets unchecked when the new button is checked.

Comment: I did try your code, but again, the user is not able to click an already selected button in order to unselect it.  I even tried using the Click event to check the value and unselect it if it was selected, but that causes the same issue I'm seeing with the ToggleButton.

Comment: You don't need to click an already selected button to unselect it. Using the ToggleButton as style, the mutual exclusion is already in-build

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96066/discussion-between-angela-f-and-aaron-hawkins).

Comment: Please actually read my question.  In the requirements, I stated, "If a user clicks on a toggle button, it's state should change from either checked to unchecked or unchecked to checked."

Comment: +1 I liked this approach ... This something similar in one of my projects.
You can still add something to uncheck the selectedRadioButton/ToggleButton if mouseOver and MouseDown ...
Then manually uncheck the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Use the GroupName attribute to achieve mutual exclusion amongst your toggle controls.

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton GroupName="Os" Content="Windows XP" IsChecked="True"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="Os" Content="Windows Vista" />
    <RadioButton GroupName="Os" Content="Windows 7" />
    <RadioButton GroupName="Office" Content="Microsoft Office 2007" IsChecked="True"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="Office" Content="Microsoft Office 2003"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="Office" Content="Open Office"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: -1 This question is specifically about the ToggleButton control.  The RadioButton control does not fulfill the requirements.

Comment: Apply a control template to my answer then. Hence, uing WPF we can separate presentation from behavior.

Comment: Please see my comments in Angela's answer which is basically the same solution aside from using the GroupName which actually has no bearing whatsoever on my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by simply a style. To test purpose, I have set the `Margin` to `5` if toggle button is `checked`; and if gets `focused` then set the control as `checked` and `Foreground` to `Red`.

```
<Style TargetType="ToggleButton" >
    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
    <Style.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
       </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
```

Comment: This seems to work tabbing into the first button, but when tabbing to the next button, even though the foreground becomes Red, the Checked event doesn't fire and it doesn't appear to actually check the next button.

Comment: Since, in my example, I have not put the handler for Checked event. Add the event is toggle button then it will work. for ex `<ToggleButton Content="1" Grid.Row="0" Checked="ToggleButton_Checked"  />`

Comment: I have a handler for that event.  What I'm saying is I'm getting strange behavior because even though the foreground color goes red when tabbing to the second button, it doesn't appear that IsChecked gets set because the background doesn't change and the checked event for the second button doesn't fire.  However, the unchecked event for the first button does fire.

Comment: It's very strange that the Unchecked event for the second button fires even though the Checked event does not.  What's even more strange is that after the second button, neither the Checked or Unchecked events fire at all until you tab back around to the first button.

Comment: I have initialized the control as `<ToggleButton Content="1" Grid.Row="0" Checked="ToggleButton_Checked" Unchecked="ToggleButton_Unchecked"  />....(other 4 Togglebuttons)` in xaml. So when I tab from screen to first toggle button to 2nd to 3rd then to 4th the output is -> ToggleButton_Checked called by System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton Content:1 IsChecked:True
ToggleButton_Unchecked called by System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton Content:1 IsChecked:False
ToggleButton_Checked called by System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton Content:2 IsChecked:True.......

Comment: Have your queries answered?