# WPF TextBox select all on Tab focus

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, keyboard-events, wpf-textbox

I'm trying to select all the text when the **focus is done with the Tab key**. But I'm not able to find the right solution. Now I'm using the **GotFocusEvent** but now when i click with the mouse it raises the event.

The code that I'm using now is:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.TextBox), System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.GotKeyboardFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(SelectAllText));


void SelectAllText(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = sender as System.Windows.Controls.TextBox;
    if (textBox != null)
        if (!textBox.IsReadOnly)
            textBox.SelectAll();
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11787674/5233410

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Referencing this answer

[Textbox SelectAll on tab but not mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11787674/5233410)

What you have can be modified to...

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.TextBox), System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.GotKeyboardFocusEvent, new KeyboardFocusChangedEventHandler(OnGotKeyboardFocus));

void OnGotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = sender as System.Windows.Controls.TextBox;

    if (textBox != null && !textBox.IsReadOnly && e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.Tab))
        textBox.SelectAll();
}
```

You should also take notice of the details about clearing the selection on `LostKeyboardFocus`

Comment: Thank you! It works, note that "RoutedEventHandler(OnGotKeyboardFocus)" should be "KeyboardFocusChangedEventHandler(OnGotKeyboardFocus)"

Comment: Got it. was a typo on my part. forgot to change it when I copied your code. fixed.

Comment: @KyloRen, guess we may never know. lol. I had up-voted your post to cancel it out. :) and also because your post is relevant.

Comment: @Nkosi +1 for your post too... someone is tracking my posts.. recently many of post has been voted down, then reversed by moderators and may be posts i'm involved with are also getting same negative voting... :(

Answer (score 1):

Use `MouseButtonState` as below:

```
 void SelectAllText(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
        {
            var textBox = sender as System.Windows.Controls.TextBox;
            if (textBox != null)
                if (!textBox.IsReadOnly)
                    textBox.SelectAll();
        }
    }
```

Comment: who is down voting for their self pleasure !! at least add comments

Comment: Thank you :) that works but meaybe it's better to handle the keyboard like the Nkosi solution